# Unable to jump to particular xml file using layout inspector in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, layout-inspector

I am working on a multi-module application that has hundreds of XML layout files. Many of these files have duplicate or similar id's. I am trying to navigate to a specific screen layout file by using the Layout Inspector in Android Studio, but when I click on the "id" attribute, I do not see a link to the corresponding XML file. Instead, I see "unknown:?" displayed. Additionally, when I try to find the specific XML file using the "Find in Path" feature in Android Studio, I am unable to locate it. How can I navigate to a specific screen layout file in this scenario?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on the

> Search Everywhere

Icon at the top-right, if I write

> *.xml

in the search row and click on the

> Files

tab, then I'm able to see all the xml files.